# Is it possible to change title font color in an application tile image on Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to change title font color in an application tile image on Windows Phone 7.1, if so, how?
For example, let's say I'm developing an application with the tile shown below, (how) can I change color of "Fake GSM Network" below to black.

[image]

Comment: You want to change the color of tiles that do not belong to your application? If so, it is not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I meant only for my own app.

Comment: In that case,  you just need to use an image with background color you want instead of transparent.

Comment: Ok but my question was if the color of the **title** text can be changed.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User can [change accent color in phone settings](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/start/change-accent-color-or-background-theme), but it will change all tiles.

You can't change a color of only one tile. You can make your application tile color static by replacing transparent background with solid one. You can't do that for applications you don't own.

You also can't change text font/color. It's always white.

Comment: So the title of the tile is always white and this can't be changed?

Answer (score 5):

You can't directly change the font color **but** you could set the Title property of the Tile to an empty string and put the text directly on the Image that you use as a Tile, with the font color that you want.

To do that, edit your `WMAppManifest.xml` file and edit the `Title` element:

```
    ...

          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <Title></Title> <-- This is the element you need to leave blank
        </TemplateType5>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
  </App>
</Deployment>
```

Comment: Would this still make it pass windows phone store certification requirements?

Comment: A lot of popular apps don't use the Title text (example: Amazon Kindle)